# embed macro to openoffice use java

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I want to ask if it is possible to embed macro(OpenOffice.org BASIC macro) to OpenOffice Document **via Java Code**, especially Open Office Impress?
If the answer if yes, what is the name of library or API I can use in order to overcome it?
I have been looking for it thoroughly in internet and cannot find any that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

http://wiki.openoffice.org/w/index.php?title=Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Writing_Macros

The docs has some good examples explaining the api. Don't waste your time to check out the forum. It is failrly unactive.